# Bigcommerce Stencil order-complete

Tags: bigcommerce

I noticed a file called `template/pages/order-complete.html` in the default Stencil theme. The content of the file is this:

```
{{#partial "page"}}
<main class="content">
    <h1>Order Complete</h1>
    <p>Your order is complete. How awesome is that!</p>
</main>
{{/partial}}
{{> layout/base}}
```

Is this file actually being used as the confirmation page? From what I can tell, it seems like the system still uses the Blueprint file `order.html`. Can anyone confirm if this is true?

Answer (score 1):

Order-complete and checkout aren't customizable through Stencil today. They are using blueprint files.

Comment: What about invoices and packing slips? I see an `invoice.scss` file. Is this file used?

Comment: I'm not immediately sure. The printable invoice (which is what that should be) has traditionally been in the blueprint template files. Based on the behavior of email templates (which were also normally bundled with BP), I'd expect invoice.scss to be a placeholder more than it is functional. You can always find out by testing.

Comment: Agreed. Haven't tested invoices but packing slips still seem to be controlled by the blueprint files even in a stencil theme.